# Can't get all elements from my DB MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am not able to get my data from the MongoAtlas database. 
My server is correctly configured since I have my data when I make a get on http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recipes
So I created two files a GlobalState and an AppReducer:

```
import AppReducer from "./AppReducer";
import axios from "axios";


// Initial state
const initialState = {
  recipes: [],
  error: null,
  loading: true,
}

// Create context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  // Actions
  async function getRecipes() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/recipes');
      console.log(res);

      dispatch({
        type: 'GET_RECIPES',
        payload: res.data.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'RECIPE_ERROR',
        payload: err.response.data.error
      });
    }
  }
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        recipes: state.recipes,
        error: state.error,
        loading: state.loading,
        getRecipes
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_RECIPES":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        recipes: action.payload
      };
    case "RECIPE_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now at first I try to recover this data and display it in one of my components:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";


import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

export const MyRecipes = () => {
  const { recipes, getRecipes } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    useEffect(() => {
      getRecipes();
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
  console.log(recipes);



  return(
    <>
      <h1>Mes Recettes</h1>
      <ul>
        {recipes.map(recipe=> (<li key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe}/>))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

As is I have an error 
×TypeError: getRecipes is not a function.
And the console.log of recipes is empty

I have put a proxy in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "qu-est-ce-qu-on-mange",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the `GlobalContextProvider` component? The `MyRecipes` component should be rendered inside the `GlobalContextProvider` component (it could any number of levels higher up in the component tree) for you to get the values from the `useContext` hook.

Comment: Ah yes I never use the GlobalProvider component
Do I have to put it in my app?                                                                             ```function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
            <Router>
      <>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/recipes" component={Recipes} />
        <Route exact path="/recipes/:id" component={RecipeDetail} />
        <Route exact path="/cookbook" component={MyRecipes} />
      </>
    </Router>
    </GlobalProvider>

  );
}```

Comment: Yes, I would put it in your app JSX.

Comment: It works thank you